# How to set css class on active menu item using a masterpage?

Tags: asp.net, css, c#-4.0, master-pages

How to set the Active menu item color when i click the sub submenu items or main item in asp.net master page.

My code is (master page source)

```
<ul class="art-menu">
      <li><a href="#" class="{ActiveItem}"><span class="l"></span><span class="r"></span><span
                            class="t">Submission</span> </a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="../QuoteStatus.aspx">Search Submission</a></li>
                                <li><a href="../NewQuote.aspx">New Submission</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="l"></span><span class="r"></span><span class="t">Requests</span></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="../Requests/IssueCertificates.aspx">Issue Certificates</a></li>
                                <li><a href="../Requests/QuoteCancellation.aspx">Cancellation</a></li>
                                <li><a href="../Requests/LossRuns.aspx">Loss Runs</a></li>
                                <li><a href="../Requests/Endorsements.aspx">Endorsements</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="l"></span><span class="r"></span><span class="t">Reports</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="l"></span><span class="r"></span><span class="t">Configuration</span></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="../Administration/UserInformation.aspx">User Information</a></li>
                                <li><a href="../SignUp.aspx">New User</a></li>
                                <li><a href="../Administration/AdminSettings.aspx">Admin Settings</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
</ul>
```

how to write the code , please give me suggestion about that...

thank u
hemanth

Comment: are you put your header in control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I do. There could be a better way. You can try it.

NOTE: your link should have `runat="server"` so you can access them from code-behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    string curlink = Request.RawUrl;

    if (curlink.Contains("/administration/school")) 
    {
        schoolinfolink.Attributes["class"] = "selected";
    }
    else if (curlink.Contains("/administration/result"))
    {
        resultlink.Attributes["class"] = "selected";
    }
    else if (curlink.Contains("/administration/staff"))
    {
       staffslink.Attributes["class"] = "selected";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familier to ASP , but in php for instance I'll handle it by adding a function that
will check which page is the current page.
I will call it above the HTML and then you can use it.

Algorithem:

1.Get current URL

2.Fetch the current file name out of it

3.save the current file name as a variable ("selectedPage")

4.When printing the menu out , use condition to compare the "selectedPage" to the item's file name.

Consider printing the menu using an array and a loop (so instead X conditions , you'll have to write just one)

Comment: Will it help I'll write it in php?