# Active elements when using Master pages

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

If I setup a `Master page` to display a header similar to the following

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-main" id="mainMenu">
    <li>
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="default.aspx">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="aboutus.aspx">About Us</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to set the element active for the current page the user is on so in html it will look like this if default.aspx is the active page.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-main" id="mainMenu">
    <li class="dropdown active"> <%--active--%>
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="default.aspx">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="aboutus.aspx">About Us</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The header menu is based on an existing template so is all html with CSS styling and does not contain any asp: controls. I know I can do this in codebehind by setting the attributes but most of the searches I've pulled up say there could be a better way or here's a dirty workaround [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914164/how-to-set-css-class-on-active-menu-item-using-a-masterpage) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989785/highlight-active-menu-items-in-master-page)

What would be the best way(s) of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to set all li tags as server Controls

```
   <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-main" id="mainMenu">
    <li>
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="default.aspx" runat="server" id="lidefault">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="aboutus.aspx" runat="server" id="liabout">About Us</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

do like the above for all li tags

Then in master page load,

```
string sURL=Request.Url.ToString().ToLower();
if (sURL.Contains("/default.aspx")
 lidefault.Attributes.Add("class", "active")
else if (sURL.Contains("/about.aspx")
 liabout.Attributes.Add("class", "active")
// do like the above for the rest li tags
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check it with javascript. Set a foreach loop for check each link of your menu. If your menu url equal the page url, add active class with .addClass() method.